# Displaying HTML Content in Windows phone Browser Field?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, webview

I am not able to display HTML content in Browser Field. My HTML:

```
 namespace webviewTest
 {
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
   {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
     private const string htmlFragment =
                 "<html><body><h2>This is an HTML fragment</h2></body></html>";

            WebView.NavigateToString(htmlFragment);
 }
 }
```

Xaml code:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="webviewTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="WebView"></phone:WebBrowser>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I know I am doing some nonsense here. Please tell me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, could it be the way you've structured your code?

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private const string htmlFragment =
           "<html><body><h2>This is an HTML fragment</h2></body></html>";

   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView.NavigateToString(htmlFragment);
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="webviewTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="WebView" />
</Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: i am gettin this errorthe name web view does noe exit in current context

Comment: Does your xaml look like this? <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="WebView"></phone:WebBrowser>  you might be confusing things, WebView exists in a Widows store apps project, I believe Android has one too.

Comment: is there any reference i have to add for displaying html content i will paste my xaml code.

Comment: have a look at the updated answer. I recommend that you get re-sharper for c#, would make your life a lot easier, at least when it comes to adding xaml references.